# LuaJava Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osx-snow-leopard, luajava

I finally managed to get LuaJava to build on OSX and now I am running into trouble using it in Eclipse.  I put the jnilib in my system path and when I go to the directory where I built it I can run the Console like this:

```
$ java -cp "luajava-1.1.jar" org.keplerproject.luajava.Console
API Lua Java - console mode.
> print("Hello World!") 
Hello World!
> exit
$
```

So I'm guessing that means that it is built and installed correctly.  I added the jar to my project using the "Add External Jar" in the Java Build Path property window.  But when I try to use it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ScriptEngineSample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ScriptEngineSample
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Here is all of my code:

**LuaWarrior.java**

```
public class LuaWarrior
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Game().start();
    }
}
```

**Game.java**

```
import org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaState;
import org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaStateFactory;

public class Game
{
    private LuaState _lua;

    public Game()
    {
        _lua = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
        _lua.openLibs();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        _lua.LdoFile("scripts/hello.lua");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it doesn't need to be in the system path, but is needs to be in the JVM Library folder.

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/
```